# How to style React Native FlatList data separately?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a standard React Native `FlatList` component that I need to style. I also have a `ListHeaderComponent` that should have its own separate styles.

My issue is that I need to style the `data` part of the `FlatList` without affecting the `ListHeaderComponent`.

I would hope to avoid a "hacky" solution, if possible. I have looked at the `FlatList` [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) and there are no props to achieve this.

Here is some code for reference

```
<FlatList
  data={DATA}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  ListHeaderComponent={<Component />}
/>
```

Worst case, is there anything else I could use to achieve this? Using a `ScrollView` to wrap the `FlatList` obviously doesn't work. I need the `FlatList` just as much as I need the styles of the `data`.

Answer (score 2):

I would style the FlatList component using the style prop for the list and use the `ListHeaderComponentStyle` prop to style the Header separately or overwrite the FlatList styling.

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation for this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#listheadercomponentstyle